# tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My presentation}
\framesubtitle{A theory}

\begin{itemize}
\item Consider the following two alternative situations:

\begin {figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tiny
\draw [thick, ->](-0.3,0)-- (0,0) -- (8,0) node [below] {Political Institutions};
\draw [thick, ->](0,-0.5)-- (0,0) -- (0,5) node [left] {Economic Institutions};
\draw (0.2,3.7) to [out=290,in=180] (3.75,1);
\draw (3.75,1) to [out=360,in=260] (7.6,3.9);
\node [above] at (7.5,4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$U$--shape relationship}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tiny
\draw [thick, ->](-0.3,0)-- (0,0) -- (8,0) node [below] {Political Institutions};
\draw [thick, ->](0,-0.5)-- (0,0) -- (0,5) node [left] {Economic Institutions};

\draw (3.75,1) to [out=360,in=260] (7.6,3.9);
\node [above] at (7.5,4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Monotonically increasing relationship}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you may notice the two graphs are one above the other, while I would like to have them side by side. How can I fix this point? In addition, the title of Figure 2 is divided into 2 lines, while I would like to have it on one line only. Thanks in advance

Comment: remove empty line between minipages.

Comment: @Zarko. Thanks it worked, but titles look very bad. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: see my answer below. i n it i suggest some improvements. maybe you will like them :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have more issues in your frame:

- images are to big ...
- axis labels i would align with axis
- instead of two mini pages in `figure` environment i would rather use columns and for caption `\captionof{figure}{<caption title>}` provided by caption `capt-of`

mwe:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}% <-- added

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My presentation}
\framesubtitle{A theory}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Consider the following two alternative situations:

\bigskip
\begin{columns}[t]
    \column{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\small
% axis
\draw [->](-0.5,0) -- node[below] {Political Institutions} (4,0);
\draw [->](0,-0.5) -- node[above,sloped] {Economic Institutions} (0,4);
% curve
\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle + (4.5,4.5);% <-- compensate influence of curve on image size
\draw [ultra thick, red] (0.2,3.5) to [out=280,in=260,looseness=3] (3.5,3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$U$--shape relationship}
    \column{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\small
% axis
\draw [->](-0.4,0) -- node[below] {Political Institutions} (4,0);
\draw [->](0,-0.4) -- node[above,sloped] {Economic Institutions} (0,4);
% curve
\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle + (4.5,4.5);% <-- compensate influence of curve on image size
\draw [ultra thick, red] (2,1) to [out=360,in=260] (4,3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Monotonically increasing relationship}
\end{columns}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: `0.5\linewidth` makes captions look better (+1)

Comment: @koleygr, thank you! we have different taste, apparently :-)

Comment: I used your answer... I have no problem to delete it if you want. The reason I added that is because sometimes I had problems with `caption` package (some conflicts) and thought it may add an alternative. [I have seen that `capt-of` used in many resent answers instead of `caption` but I am not sure if it may conflicts too with possible other packages as `caption` does] You may add the alternative to your answer and delete mine if you want... (to be honest I prefer the last than keeping it)

Comment: @Dario, you are welcome! you can also up-vote it :-).

Comment: @Zarko I have already voted for your answer! :)

Comment: @Dario, thank you very much! sometimes i'm too impatient :-(

Comment: @Zarko not a problem. Your kind help would deserve more than one vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Its @Zarko's answer (so, do not accept it) in case you don't want to use `capt-of` package but minipages and figures instead:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{capt-of}% <-- added

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My presentation}
\framesubtitle{A theory}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Consider the following two alternative situations:

  \bigskip
  \begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\small
% axis
\draw [->](-0.5,0) -- node[below] {Political Institutions} (4,0);
\draw [->](0,-0.5) -- node[above,sloped] {Economic Institutions} (0,4);
% curve
\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle + (4.5,4.5);% <-- compensate influence of curve on image size
\draw [ultra thick, red] (0.2,3.5) to [out=280,in=260,looseness=3] (3.5,3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$U$--shape relationship}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}%
     \begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\small
% axis
\draw [->](-0.4,0) -- node[below] {Political Institutions} (4,0);
\draw [->](0,-0.4) -- node[above,sloped] {Economic Institutions} (0,4);
% curve
\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle + (4.5,4.5);% <-- compensate influence of curve on image size
\draw [ultra thick, red] (2,1) to [out=360,in=260] (4,3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Monotonically increasing relationship}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: You may use `[t]` option like `\begin{minipage}[t,inner sep=0]{0.5\linewidth}` as @Zarko  suggests

Comment: probably you should add option [t] to mini pages (they have different height due to caption).